# How to get the org-mode priority value?

Tags: org-mode

I want to get the value of the org-mode priority from the heading the cursor is under.

I ideally want a function that, ran under a heading with "[#A]", should return A as a character or string

Any guidance will be appriciated.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Whatever it is, turning a number into a string, concatenating it with some other junk, turning that into a symbol and then into a byte is probably the wrong way to do it.

Comment: org-priority-show gets the priority of a heading in OrgMode. It gives the value as 64000 (the 64 is an example, it can be different), I'm dividing it by 1000 to get 64 and if I concatenate 64 to get #o64. If I run #o64 into byte-to-sting, I get the value I wanted.

Comment: There must be a much better method, probably with a regexp, but I have no idea how to achieve that.

Comment: All I want is the org-priority value. For a heading with [#A], I want to get A.

Comment: Ok, so you just want the priority letter out of the current buffer?

Comment: Out of the orgmode heading it's under.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Please edit the question, in particular the title, to express what you want to know. It seems that the question is not really about converting a string to a symbol.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have changed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the priority letter itself without jumping through any hoops like this:

```lisp
(defun db48x/org-get-priority-letter ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((pri (cdr (assoc "PRIORITY"
                         (org-entry-properties nil
                                               "PRIORITY")))))
    (message "priority=%s" pri)))
```

Comment: Or even simpler: `(org-entry-get nil "PRIORITY")`